# facial expression of sympathetic pain?

Tags: phrase-requests

What would you call a facial expression displayed at sight of someone hurting - the kind of involuntary grimace when you imagine just how much it hurt?

Comment: Hi, (it's me again) every so often I go through posts which have "How do you call....?" or "How are ______ called?"  in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing your question to *“**What** would you call a facial...?”* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**flinch**
verb
past tense: flinched; past participle: flinched
1.
make a quick, nervous movement of the face or body as an instinctive reaction to fear or pain.

a synonym would be **wince**

Comment: I do not think *flinch* and *wince* are synonyms, but I do think *wince* is the word OP is looking for.

Comment: I agree with @onomatomaniak. Flinching is more of a movement, wincing can be more of a scrunching of the face.

Comment: I think you would need to call it a 'sympathetic wince' wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Another good word to describe this reaction would be **cringe**, *experience an inward shiver of embarrassment or disgust.* or *to shrink, bend, or crouch, especially in fear or servility; cower.*